# How can I convert my Facebook profile to a Page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I heard that it is possible to convert my Facebook account to become a Facebook page.

I created my Facebook account, and now I want to move the account to become a page so as to make it my official Facebook page.

Comment: I am giving you the benefit of the doubt here, but please do not use the site as a means to promote a blog.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions at [https://www.facebook.com/help/175644189234902](https://www.facebook.com/help/175644189234902/)
They have additional questions there that you should consider before converting, such as what will be transferred and can you convert back. However, if you are sure you wish to convert, then the instructions are:

1. Go to https://www.facebook.com/pages/create/migrate
2. Click **Get Started** to follow the on-screen directions

Please keep in mind that:

- You can only convert your profile to a Page once.
- You'll have a personal account and a Page after completing the
  conversion, and you'll be able to manage the Page from your personal
  account.
- The tools to help you move info from your profile to your Page will
  only be available for 14 days after you complete the conversion.